# application-level dynamic power and performance settings?

Tags: power-management

I'm wondering if I can stay in a low-power state, except when I'm interacting with a particular application, in which case I'd like to enter a high-performance / high-power consumption state.

This transitioning should be automatic, and once I switch away from the application the laptop should again go back to a low-power state.

Is it feasible to script this behavior?

Comment: It's not clear what you consider a "low power" state to be. To many, that would mean one of the [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) sleep states, but perhaps you meant something different.

Comment: @user535733 yes, I mean low-power processor states in the page you linked above. I don't know if power management and CPU frequency scaling applies to the entire CPU package or if individual cores are also addressable (in mobile CPUs).